# What does !$ means in Bash scripting?

Tags: command-line, bash

When reading the content of a script, I found something like:

```
echo "An Example" > !$
```

So I wonder what does `!$` mean in bash .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i found that !$ means **last argument** so for an example :

```
touch /tmp/file1
```

Here the argument is **/tmp/file1** , so **!$** replaced `/tmp/file1` in echo example .

If then you type the command `du -b !$` , the output will be the disk usage in bytes for `/tmp/file1`

Comment: Your answer has some problems: 1. **last argument** from where? 2. The answer is not true is you use that command in a script as you said (read [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/496120/147044) until the end to understand why)!

Answer (score 9):

From `man bash` (somewhere after the line 3813):

> ```
> !      Start  a  history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
>           newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option
>           is enabled using the shopt builtin).
>
> [...]
>
> $      The  last  word.   This  is  usually the last argument, but will
>           expand to the zeroth word if there is only one word in the line.
> ```

So, the `!$` will recall the last argument from the last command from history.

Here are some examples and equivalents:

```bsh
$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo !$ # recall the last argument from the last command from history
echo bar
bar

$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo !:$ # the same like `!$'
echo bar
bar

$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo !:2  # recall the second (in this case the last) argument from the last command from history
echo bar
bar

$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo $_ # gives the last argument from the last command from history
bar

$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo Alt+. # pressing Alt and . (dot) in the same time will automatically insert the last argument from the last command from history
bar

$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo Alt+_ # the same like when you press Alt+.
bar

$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ echo Esc. # the same like when you press Alt+.
bar
```

All of these will work only inside of an **interactive shell**. But if you use that command from your question inside of a script as you said that you sow it, then the things are different: when you run the script, this will start in a new shell, a **non-interactive** shell, so the history expansion doesn't has any effect in this case and so the command:

```
echo "An Example" > !$
```

creates the file `!$` if not present (otherwise overwrites it) and write `An Example` into it.